# How to navigate to activity located in different module

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on application which is divided by features into modules.

App structure looks like so:

- app (application)

  - MainActivity
  - MainApplication
- featureOne (module)

  - FirstActivity
- featureTwo (module)

  - SecondActivity

Feature modules cannot depend on each other, but I can edit them freely. 
My goal is to navigate from FirstActivity to SecondActivity.

I cannot use `startActivity(Intent(com.example.featureTwo.SecondActivity))`, because SecondActivity class is not visible to FirstActivity(different independent module).

Question is what is the proper way to navigate from FirstActivity to SecondActivity?

I was thinking about using:

- Broadcast - I would send broadcast from FristActivity and register broadcast receiver, in featureTwos manifest. From broadcastReceiver I would launch SecondActivity.
- Deep Links - Similar to the broadcastReceiver.
- Creating function in application class and an enum within app package containint activies I want to launch. I would call this function whenever I want to launch activity like so: `launchActivityFromDifferentModule(EnumWithActivities.SecondActivity)`.

Which method should I use, which one I shouldn't and why?

Comment: Use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) with `Strings`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano if I understand correctly I would still need to have SecondActivity defined in FirstActivity which seems kind of ugly, because I would need to remember about keeping the string with the class name up to date.

Comment: You can use resources

Answer (score 2):

have many approaches for lunching activity in another module

1. Reflection

   Props: easily navigate to another class without define class in the app module.

   Cons:  reflection is running at runtime.
2. DeepLink

   Props: create a unique link for any item in another module like openFragmentA, addCreditToUserAccount, etc.

   Cons: not have a serious concern.
3. Broadcast

   Props: declare determined activity in the app module (if have nav module setup inside).

   Cons: need more time to change and define another module.

Conclusion

Deeplink is suitable for a dynamic feature (onDemand feature)
Broadcast is suitable for a main feature, permanently feature
Reflection is suitable when not confident for a feature like A/B test feature

Answer (score 1):

The approach Google recommends by the moment is to use reflection to navigate between feature modules.

In my case, I have created a new navigation module to hosts the different classes of navigation. My App module depends on this module so every feature module can access the navigation.

I use a file with functions to instantiate `Intent`'s through reflection:

```
private const val PACKAGE_NAME = "com.your_app_package_name"

private fun intentTo(className: String): Intent =
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setClassName(PACKAGE_NAME, className)

internal fun String.loadIntentOrNull(): Intent? =
    try {
        Class.forName(this).run { intentTo(this@loadIntentOrNull) }
    } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
        null
    }
```

Note as the `loadIntentOrNull` String extension is internal, it will be only available in the navigation module.

Then you can create objects for each module to handle the navigation.

```
object SearchNavigation : Navigation {

    private const val SEARCH = "com.your_search_activity_package"

    override fun getIntent(): Intent? = SEARCH.loadIntentOrNull()
}
```

The Navigation interface just defines the `getIntent` method:

```
interface Navigation {
    fun getIntent(): Intent?
}
```

Then you can inject this Navigation object in every module as your feature module depends on the app module, and at the same time, it depends on the navigation module.

Following your structure, it would be something like this

- app (application)

  - MainActivity
  - MainApplication
- featureOne (module)

  - FirstActivity
- featureTwo (module)

  - SecondActivity
- navigation (module)

  - featureOneNavigation (object)
  - featureTwoNavigation (object)

The app module will depend on the navigation module. featureOne and featureTwo will depend on app (because they are feature modules) and will have access to the navigation.

You can also avoid creating a new module for the navigation and implement this just in the app module.

This method can be also applied to instantiate Fragments, so you can have your host activity with a DrawerLayout in your app module, and each of its Fragments in a different module.

Answer (score -2):

**Add your modules in the build.gradle file**

```
android {
   ...
}

dependencies {
    ..

    implementation project(':featureOne')
    implementation project(':featureTwo')
}
```

**Note:**
Libraries/modules should be developed in a way that they are independent, and they should be divided by functionality.

Comment: My app build.gradle is dependant on featureOne and featureTwo, but that does not solve the problem.